# Question on using "be worth"

Tags: grammar

1. It's worth visiting London.
2. London is worth visiting.
3. Visiting London is worth it.
4. It's worth it to visit London.

Are all these sentences grammatically correct? Do they have the same meaning? Which of them sounds most natural to you?

Thanks so much!

Comment: They're all just fine. _Worth_ is a complex word, [along with _cost, price,_ and _value_,](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) and has its own complex syntax.